# QFileDialog нажимаю cancel но все равно выходит окно

Tags: c++, qt, qfiledialog

Здраствуйте при нажатии на кнопку я вызываю`QFileDialog` но при нажатии кнопку Cancel или при нажатии на крестик в диалогов окне в QFileDialog, мое окно все равно окно все равно создается. Я новичок поэтому не ругайтесь)))
тот самый фрагмент кода когда я вызываю `QFileDialog`:

```
    QString ImageName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, tr("Choose image"),"", tr("Images (*.png *.jpg *.jpeg *.bmp *.gif)"));

if(QString::compare(ImageName,QString()) !=0)
{
    QImage image;
    bool valid = image.load(ImageName);

    if(valid)
    {
        ui->lbl_image->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(image));
    }
    else
    {
        QMessageBox::warning(this, "error", "could not open the image");
    }
}
```

Comment: `QString::compare(ImageName,QString()) !=0`

Answer (score 0):

Если в диалоге нажали "отмена", диалог возвращает нулевую строку

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html#getOpenFileName

Проверка на нулевую строку в Qt делается методом `isNull`, для нулевой строки проверка `isEmpty` также вернет `true`

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#isEmpty

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#isNull

> Qt makes a distinction between null strings and empty strings for historical reasons. For most applications, what matters is whether or not a string contains any data, and this can be determined using the isEmpty() function.

В вашем случае

```cpp
QString ImageName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName ...
if(!ImageName.isEmpty())
{
...
```

Comment: Я, конечно, не специалист в QT, но по вашей ссылке написано: If the user presses Cancel, it returns a _null string_

Comment: Правильное замечание, но для нулевой строки проверка на isEmpty также возвращает true https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#isEmpty

Comment: @АртёмОконечников дополнил ответ пояснением про нулевые и пустые строки

Comment: Хорошо. А можете объяснить автору, что не так с этим кодом `QString::compare(ImageName, QString()) != 0`?

Comment: Это интересный вопрос, потому что у меня код автора отрабатывает как положено